# How to automate installation of packages with .emacs file?

Tags: init-file, package, install

My `~/.emacs` (which you can find [on GitHub](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/master/.emacs)) file loads several different Emacs packages and I would like them to be automatically installed as soon as Emacs starts up, if they are not already installed. This way if I have to reinstall my Ubuntu 16.04 operating system again I will not have to install each package myself manually using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install`. Is there a way to write an `~/.emacs` file so that it will automatically install all loaded packages on startup? I would like this to be done with the minimum of lines as I have over ten different packages loaded so if I have to add extra lines for each individual package it will make my `~/.emacs` rather long.

Comment: There are several ways, but you should use https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package

Comment: Is it possible to load multiple packages in a single line with `use-package`, like I do on [line 61](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/735e055cd975235222c59f05d5869808efb39a94/.emacs#L61) of my .emacs file?

Comment: See `package-install-selected-packages` (requires Emacs 25.1).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it such a desirable property to have all of your packages listed on a single line?  The only reason that you give is to keep your `~/.emacs` file from getting "long."  But if you are only loading a dozen packages, are you really concerned about the extra 11 lines in your config?

Comment: Well this was a few months ago so I don't remember my specific thinking but I suspect it was along the lines of trying to minimize how much work is required when I add or subtract a package from the list that is automatically installed. Didn't want multiple lines being added to the file for each separate package installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is to install [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

```el
(package-initialize)
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

(dolist (package '(use-package))
   (unless (package-installed-p package)
       (package-install package)))
```

Then

```
 (use-package paredit
   :ensure t)
```

The `:ensure t` is what ensures that the package is installed.

To just load ensure multiple packages are install

```
(dolist (package '(package-a package-b package-c))
 (unless (package-installed-p package)
   (package-install package))
   (require package))))
```

Comment: Can you specify multiple packages for it to load on a single line?

Comment: If you mean use-package then no, but the expression above, can be

Comment: Well my question is about multiple packages so please edit your answer so that it does just that, loads and if not present, automatically installs, multiple packages.

Comment: the dolist can be changed to '(use-package 'some-other-package), but no other configuration can be done. I would recommend having a line for each package with use-package.

Comment: I have over ten different packages loaded so a more compact solution would be desirable.

Comment: I would still disagree, but I will modify the example

Comment: OK, your answer is a little confusing. `paredit` isn't a package I have enabled in my `~/.emacs` so do I still add ` (use-package paredit     :ensure t)` to my `~/.emacs` along with the other lines in your answer? PS. on line 3 of the final bit of your answer I think ya want `package-install pacakge` to be replaced with `package-install package`.

Comment: No, my example was clipped from my init.el so paredit is one of my packages installed, use should substitute your packages.  `package-install` is how it is in my init.el, so not sure if `package-install-package` would work.

Comment: I should substitute my packages (i.e., plural, or multiple packages) or package? I thought `use-package` was for a single package?

Comment: Ok, reread you last comment and you are correct there is a typo, there that needs correction.

Comment: If you do now what one line for each package then don't use use-package. Use the last example in the original answer, and substitute your packages for package-a package-b package-c

Comment: @njdan5691 You should have something like `(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))`, because unless you have somehow refreshed the package archives at least once, you can't install anything.  Note that this hits the network.  Also, the `(require 'package)` is redundant, because `package-initialize` is autoloaded.

Answer (score 6):

`package.el` keeps track of the packages you asked to install (as opposed to those that are auto-installed as dependencies) in the custom variable `package-selected-packages`.

So if you copy your `~/.emacs` (in which Custom normally writes settings like that of `package-selected-packages`) to another system, all you should need to do is `M-x package-install-selected-packages`.

Of course, this doesn't automatically install the packages if they're absent, but I consider it a feature (I think it's a mistake for a program like Emacs to make network connections without an explicit request to do so).  And it does save you the trouble of installing each package one by one.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to share my use case, which is different than that of the OP: I'm often transferring my dotfiles between machines (especially cloud, where they are created and killed all the time). The package directory is quite hefty, with elpy v-env and the kitchen sink, especially given old versions are not auto-trimmed, AFAIK. It's much easier to drop in a few small files and reinstall packages than carry them around.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing: `(package-refresh-contents)` needs to be invoked once before `(package-install-selected-packages)` when the local package directory is entirely missing, so that package distribution archive directories are cached first in subdirectories of its `archive/` directory.